# Scrolling an iframe in a div – not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a very simple setup:

```
<div style="height: 100vh; overflow-y: scroll; padding: 24px">
  <iframe src="..." style="height: 1500px" />
</div>
```

The `iframe` has a static height and I'd like to simply scroll the div that's wrapping it. The thing is – I can't – it does not work. It only works when the cursor is on the padding area around the `iframe`, yet not if the cursor is on the `iframe` itself.

Any idea how (and if) it could be solved?

Comment: Hi, on what platform are you trying to scroll ? I had the same problem on iOS and it turned out that it is no longer possible to scroll in an iframe on Safari. For Desktop/android, try to add `scrolling="yes"` to you <iframe> tag.

Comment: @MathiAs2Pique_ I'm using macOS / iOS for that. I'll try adding the attribute!

Comment: Oh, so you'll probably get an error, last time I tried, it was just scrolling 100vh, not more.